# How can I interchange the values of a number of columns depending on a key using awk or perl?

Tags: perl, awk, key

Is there a simple way of interchanging columns in a tabulated file like this?

The keys would be the first and third column but the second column should be appended to the first key and the 4th column to the third. 
The swap between the columns depends on the existence of the first key(1st col) against the second key(3rd column).

```
A B C D    
E F A B
H I A G
J K L M 
N J Q K
```

The desired output would be like this:

```
A B C D    
A B E F
A G H I 
J K L M 
N J Q K
```

Comment: Do you mean A in the 3rd column is swapped because A exists somewhere in the first column before swapping?

Comment: Exactly. If A is found somewhere in column 3, I would like to change it to the first column but without losing the info of the forth column which is related to A and keeping its hit with E that its appended to F, for example.

Answer (score 1):

this works for you: I could make it in a "one-liner", but I think that I paste in this way is easier to read.

```
awk 'NR==1{a[$1];print;next;}!($1 in a){
r="";h=$1;
for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)
    if($i in a){
        for(m=i;m<=NF;m++)
            r=(r?r" ":"")$m
            break;
        }else{
        h=h" "$i
    }
    $0=(r?r" ":"")h;
}1' file
```

test with your data:

```
kent$ echo "A B C D    
E F A B
H I A G
J K L M 
N J Q K"|awk 'NR==1{a[$1];print;next;}!($1 in a){
r="";h=$1;
for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)
        if($i in a){
                for(m=i;m<=NF;m++)
                        r=(r?r" ":"")$m
                        break;
                }else{
                h=h" "$i
        }
        $0=(r?r" ":"")h;
}1'
A B C D    
A B E F
A G H I
J K L M
N J Q K
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm trying it with my actual data :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simpler solution using Perl. This will fail if two odd columns on the same line have the same contents, e.g.

```
C D C A # Would print out "C A" only
```

Otherwise, we can use the hash data structure that provides easy manipulation of key-value pairs.

```
perl -ple'%h=split;$_=join" ",map{$_=>$h{$_}}sort keys %h'
```

Example Usage:

```
$ perl -ple'%h=split;$_=join" ",map{$_=>$h{$_}}sort keys %h' <<'END'
A B C D    
E F A B
H I A G
J K L M 
N J Q K
END
```

Output:

```
A B C D
A B E F
A G H I
J K L M
N J Q K
```

**Without that weakness**, I would write it like

```
perl -pale'@f=();push@f,[splice@F,0,2]while@F;$_=join" ",map@$_,sort{$a->[0]cmp$b->[0]}@f'
```

which essentially does a Schwartzian Transform.

### Explanations

#### 1st solution:

The option `-l` handles line endings for us. `-p` loops over all input lines (putting them in `$_`) and prints out the contents of `$_` after each iteration.

A hash is constructed as a list of alternating keys and values. The `split` function without options splits the contents of `$_` on whitespace, and returns a list which we assign to the hash `%h`. Duplicate keys are removed; only the last occurrence is set.

We `sort` the `keys` alphabetically. `map` takes each key and transforms the list of keys into a list of alternating keys and values, but in the correct order this time.

We `join` this list of strings via a single space and assign it to `$_`, which is printed because of `-p`.

#### 2nd solution:

The `-a` options auto`split`s the `$_` into the `@F` array. We take the first two elements of `@F` with `splice`, put them into an anonymous arrayref, and push this arrayref into `@f` array. We repeat until no elems are left. This pairs the contents of `@F`, and isn't bothered by duplicates.

We `sort` the arrayrefs in `@f` by their first element alphabetically, and flatten the resulting order with `map`. After that, we join the strings as before.

Comment: Thanks a lot! this works smoothly with my actual data, I would not have the risk of that weakness because my keys are never the same. Again, thanks!

Comment: @hamadryadz The second solution `perl -pale ...` doesn't have that weakness.